# How does Go invoke Ticker by interval?

Tags: go, concurrency

Since I am not experinced Go developer, I didn't understand way of working with Ticker. I have following scenario:

A go web service running on specific port 8080, it is getting data from another applications and processing the data. So far so good, but I have a another `sendData` function in this web service which loop through the some files and send them to another extern service. I am trying to call the `sendData()` function every 1 minute. Here is how main function looks without Tickers:

```
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/data", headers)          //line 1
    log.Printf("Ready for data ...%s\n", 8080) //line 2
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)          //line 3
}
```

If I add the Ticker after `line 2` it's keeping loop infinitively.
If I add after `line 3`, the programm is not invoking the Ticker.
Any idea how to handle this?

The Ticker part

```
ticker := schedule(sendData, time.Second, done)
time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
close(done)
ticker.Stop()
```

and the [schedule from](https://go.dev/play/p/HogqmrdYDSk)

```
func schedule(f func(), interval time.Duration, done <-chan bool) *time.Ticker {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                f()
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return ticker
```

So basically I want to sendData evert minute or hour etc. Could someone explain how internally Ticker works?

Comment: A `Ticker` sends the time value over the `Ticker.C` channel on every "tick", exactly as the documentation states. What question do you have about how it works?

Comment: The Ticker will call per interval, but here is behaving like infinite loop.

Comment: How is "one tick per interval" different from "behaving like an infinite loop"? You could create a ticker yourself with a loop, it just wouldn't be optimized within the runtime scheduler. The only other infinite loop here is the one you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` runs an infinite `for` loop listening for  inbound connections, that's why the ticker is not invoked if you call it afterwards.

And then here

```
ticker := schedule(sendData, time.Second, done)
time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
close(done)
ticker.Stop()
```

you're exiting the loop inside `schedule()` after 60 seconds, so your ticker will run only once or won't run at all (depending on whether the done channel receives the value before or later that the ticker ticks, as they are concurrent we cannot determine their order)

---

So what you want is the following

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/data", headers)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute)
    go schedule(ticker)

    log.Printf("Ready for data ...%s\n", 8080)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func schedule(ticker *time.Ticker) {
    for {
        // This blocks until a value is received, the ticker
        // sends a value to it every one minute (or the interval specified)
        <-ticker.C
        fmt.Println("Tick")
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, once the server connection is interrupted the program will terminate so there's no point on having a `done` channel to exit the loop.

[Try it here](https://go.dev/play/p/Ipfdq3hPhJm)

Comment: I think this answer over simplifies the original ask. You have launched the scheduler in a separate go routine which eliminates the deadlock in the question (as I did in my answer). But the done channel can still be a useful tool to close the schedule, especially if for example the ticker was replaced with a listener for an external message queue.

Answer (score -2):

You are on the right track - you just need to wrap the ticker declaration in a self executing function and then run it as a goroutine. `ListenAndServe` and `Schedule` are both blocking tasks, so they need to run on separate go routines. Luckily go makes this really simple to achieve.

*Note - this sample code is meant to stay as close to your example as possible. I would recommend separating the declaration of the ticker from the schedule func.*

```
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {}) //line 1

    var done chan bool

    go func() {
        ticker := schedule(func() { fmt.Println("Tick") }, time.Second, done)
        time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
        close(done)
        ticker.Stop()
    }()

    fmt.Printf("Ready for data ...%v\n", 8080) //line 2
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)          //line 3
}
```